# Altair Chart in Python: how to remove the counpound chart border for the 'HConcatChart'

Tags: python, altair

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

iris = data.iris.url

chart1 = alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    height=300,
    width=300
)

chart2 = alt.Chart(iris).mark_bar().encode(
    x='count()',
    y=alt.Y('petalWidth:Q', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=30)),
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    height=300,
    width=100
)

alt.hconcat(chart1, chart2).ViewConfig(strokeWidth = 0)
```

Is there any way to make the border of these two horizontal charts disabled? The .config_view is not available for compound charts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.configure_view()` method on the concatenated chart to remove the view border in each subchart:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

iris = data.iris.url

chart1 = alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    height=300,
    width=300
)

chart2 = alt.Chart(iris).mark_bar().encode(
    x='count()',
    y=alt.Y('petalWidth:Q', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=30)),
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    height=300,
    width=100
)

alt.hconcat(chart1, chart2).configure_view(strokeWidth = 0)
```

[image]